# ERROR: requested character too large for encoding: 14844072

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am converting following line of code from Oracle to PostgreSQL.

In Oracle:

```
select CHR(14844072) from dual
```

Output:

```
" "
```

In postgresql:

```
select CHR(14844072);
```

Getting an error:

> SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: requested character too large for encoding:
> 14844072

Comment: Can you please run in postgresql: SHOW client_encoding;

Comment: I am not sure CHR(14844072) mean. but I found out this link. I am not sure it helps. https://stevemorse.org/hebrew/utf8.html?charset=70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the function is different from Oracle to Postgresql.

In oracle the statement is valid. So is, for example:

```
select CHR(0) from dual;
```

While in Postgresql, you can't SELECT CHR(0):

> chr(0) is disallowed because text data types cannot store that
> character.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html

This is just an example. More specific: what do you expect with value 14844072? Empty string is nonsense for Postgresql.

In Oracle you have this situation:

- For single-byte character sets, if n > 256, then Oracle Database returns the binary equivalent of n mod 256
- For multibyte character sets, n must resolve to one entire code point

But:

> Invalid code points are not validated, and the result of specifying
> invalid code points is indeterminate.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions019.htm

In PostgreSQL the function depends from encoding, but, assuming you use UTF8:

> In UTF8 encoding the argument is treated as a Unicode code point. In
> other multibyte encodings the argument must designate an ASCII
> character

Short answer: you need to work on the application code OR build your own function, something like this (just en example):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myCHR(integer) RETURNS TEXT
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF $1 = 0 THEN
        RETURN '';
    ELSE 
        IF $1 <= 1114111 THEN --replace the number according to your encoding
            RETURN CHR($1);
        ELSE
            RETURN '';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What is `EXAMPLEVALUE ` here?

Comment: Sorry @MAK I didn't specified. It is the max usable value for your encoding. For example 1114111 in UTF8

Comment: Updated function to have a working example out of the box

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, this function expects an UTF8 encoded value. Now 14844072 in hex is E280A8, which corresponds to the UNICODE code point hex 2028, the "line separator" character.

In PostgreSQL, `chr()` expexts the code point as argument. So feed it the decimal value that corresponds to hex 2028:

```
SELECT chr(8232);
```